# Why can't I retrieve a number of friends if my app has been granted a user_friends permission by default on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm very confused why `Graph API` returns only id value when i call this:

```
$response->get('/10207252567926988?fields=id,friends&access_token='.$accessToken);
```

**Note**: this ID is app-scoped user ID, and user has authorized my app. This is app access token, not user access token(but same happens when i replace it with user access token). Here is what it says in `developers.facebook.com` 
[image]

So `user_friends` permission in approved by default, and still i get empty response from `Graph`. Could it be due to this few permissions from picture above being login permissions so that only while being in process of logging into my app user can give me his number of friends data and not afterwards? Is it possible to get `total_count` of friends without user `accessToken` but with app `accessToken`?

Comment: why not use /me instead of the user id? using the user id is pointless. and of course you need a user token, an app token does not have any relation to a user.

Comment: Did you _ask_ the user for the permission, _and_ did they grant it? (Approved by Facebook does not mean granted by the user, those are two completely different things.) Plus, you will only get to see friends that are using the same app, and have granted it the permission as well. If there are no such friends, then you will only get the total count.

Comment: Total count is all I'm interested in. But if `user_friends` permission is granted by default, doesn't it mean that when user authorizes my app he approves this permission as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your app can only get access to/return the current user's friends THAT ALSO are users of your app and that have given your app the `user_friends` permission as well.
2. Yes, by specifying the `user_friends` permission in the scope of your `Fb.login()` call, your app will prompt the user for that permission.  For instance:

   ```
   FB.login(
     callbackFunction,
     { scope: "public_profile,email,user_friends" }
   );
   ```
3. HOWEVER, the user could always decline to grant the "user_friends" position by click "No" when prompted.

   - In order to force it, you would have to immediately check that the user, in fact, did grant that permission, and ....
   - if not, re-request login with that scope AND prevent further app functionality unless you receive it.
4. BUT... **even if** the user DOES GRANT your app the permission, if they don't have any friends who use the app, or those friends don't grant your app the `user_friends` permission, then you will ONLY see a total count of friends.